# Jquery autocomplete not working on ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

- **Tutorial I am following**

Hi, I am implementing jquery autocomplete using this tutorial
**ASP.NET Tutorial Part 76 Implement autocomplete textbox functionality in mvc**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmBdMZJ3Jlo

- **Problem**

When I type something in input box, autocomplete does not work

- **Description**

I have implemented the search functionality and its working fine but i am stuck on autocomplete function of jquery. I have searched a lot on google and stack overflow previous questions, i tried everything but couldn't solve my problem.

- **Code**

Here is my code of autocomplete ( i have not included code of searching )

*Index.cshtml*

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("GetAirports")'
            });
    });

</script>

 @using(@Html.BeginForm())
 {
        <br />
        <b>AirPort Code:</b>
        @Html.TextBox("SearchTerm", null, new { id="txtSearch"})
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />     
 }
```

and my controller code

*HomeController.cs*

```
public JsonResult GetAirports(string term)
{
            traveloticketEntities db = new traveloticketEntities();
            List<String> Airports = new List<String>();
            Airports = db.IataAirportCodes.Where(x => x.code.StartsWith(term)).Select(y=>y.code).ToList();
            return Json(Airports, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: Did you check the client side console for errors?

Comment: @mason sorry but i dont know what is client side console. But I tried to debug it manually and i think autocomplete function is not being called when i type something in textbox.

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools (usually F12 on your keyboard). Look for the console or JavaScript tab. Look for any errors there.

Comment: @mason i checked it and there are no errors on client side.

Comment: In that case, add `console.log` calls to your JavaScript code to confirm that it reaches the code and executes it. Also monitor the network tab of your browser's debug tool to see if any HTTP requests go out from your page.

Comment: @Junaid, Did you check if your controller is actually returning Airports given a specific term?

Comment: @mason I looked closely and you were right i caught an error. The error is "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function"

Comment: @Junaid Did you make sure your page has a proper reference to the jQuery libraries?

Comment: @FrankFajardo yes i checked it. It is returning json data

Comment: @mason i downloaded the autocomplete widget from jquery site and added .js files to script folder and .css files to content folder and then dragged and dropped them directly from solution explorer to my Index.cshtml file.

Comment: @Junaid You need to update your question to show how you're doing it on the page. Just describing it doesn't do it justice. And look at the network traffic like I said: see if jQuery library is being pulled down when you load the page. If it's not, double check the path that it's trying to pull it from.

Comment: Ok @mason I will update my question and will let you know about network traffic

Comment: You're referencing both `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery-ui.min.j`. Don't do that. Reference the unminified one during development, and the minified one on production.

Comment: I tried both the ways. No success :(

Comment: I didn't expect fixing the double reference to work, but it's something you needed to do anyways. Now, like I've said several times now: watch the network traffic. Does it load the jQuery library and jQuery UI libraries? Do you see any HTTP requests going to your MVC action?

Comment: Ok i am doing that right now. I will let you know

Comment: I got Solution @mason thank you so much for your help. The jQuery libraries were not being loaded. Because the references of other jQuery libraries in _Layout.cshtml were overwriting them. I removed the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution. Thanks a lot @mason for your help. I checked my code on client side console (google chrome console using F12) and there i found out that _Layout.cshtml were adding other jQuery libraries at the end of my index.cshtml file, which were overwriting my libraries in index.cshtml. So i removed this code from _Layout.css

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

and placed my jQuery libraries in Index.cshtml in the following order

```
<script src="~/Scripts/external/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which version of Visual Studio you are using.  In 2013, I didn't have any problem with jquery autocomplete.  However, in 2015, they didn't include the jquery ui scripts.  I had to add it through nuget, then add it to bundleConfig.cs before it worked.

My scripts section includes the following:
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

Why didn't Microsoft include the jquery ui in Visual Studio 2015?  I'd love to know the answer to this.