# Google maps api autocomplete not working on ASP.net mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

i am new in asp net mvc4 programming and now I am trying to make an auto complete maps location and get the address and latitude and longitude.

**Tutorial**
I am following tutorial from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kHz9snOS-U ...
Both of them works perfectly in a single .html that i make from notepad(i use my google api key).

**Problem** The problem here is when i implemented the code in my project in C# asp.net mvc4, the auto complete is not working and i tried to F12 in my browser it telling me this :
[image]

**Tried Solution** i've tried this solution [Jquery autocomplete not working on ASP.NET MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236097/jquery-autocomplete-not-working-on-asp-net-mvc-5) it says that it's implement the _layout and i tried to make my layout null but still it doesn't work for me.

Here's my code :

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Autocomplete</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='change it to api key'&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', intilize);
        function intilize() {
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("txtautocomplete"));

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                var location = "Address: " + place.formatted_address + "<br/>";
                location += "Latitude: " + place.geometry.location.lat() + "<br/>";
                location += "Longitude: " + place.geometry.location.lng();
                document.getElementById('lblresult').innerHTML = location
            });

        };

    </script>

    <span>location:</span><input type="text" id="txtautocomplete" style="width:200px" placeholder="enter the adress" />
    <br><label id="lblresult"></label>

    <script src="@SiteHelper.GetBaseUrl()/Assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@SiteHelper.GetBaseUrl()/Assets/global/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me why my code doesn't work on .cshtml and how is the solution ?

Comment: You should be checking that the place does contain a geometry - `if (!place.geometry) { console.log('no geometry'); return; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank's i added it but the Autocomplete still not working

Comment: Hi @Shasapo ...First check " place " object has the value.

Comment: @PonmaniChinnaswamy hi ponmany, i've console.log the places and it returned `Object {name: "bandung"}`

Comment: @Shasapo .. your code is perfectly working for me... check the jquery libraries are added correctly..